# vim always generate <++> after typing ()

Tags: vim

I am not sure which plugin generated this behavior, whenever I type closed bracket right after opening bracket,  a <++> will be appended right after. Below is my plugin list. Not sure what goes wrong, I could not use the latex editing features of the plugin.

In general, I would like to ask, is there a way to check the compatibility of each plugin?

```
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'gbritton1/python_match'
Plugin 'dbakker/vim-projectroot'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'int3/vim-extradite'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'jalvesaq/vimcmdline'
Plugin 'w0rp/ale'
Plugin 'mattn/mkdpreview-vim'
Plugin 'skywind3000/asyncrun.vim'
Plugin 'mllg/vim-devtools-plugin'
Plugin 'jalvesaq/Nvim-R'
Plugin 'joonty/vim-sauce.git'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/Lynx-Offline-Documentation-Browser'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plugin 'chrisbra/csv.vim'
Plugin 'kannokanno/previm'
Plugin 'rhysd/vim-grammarous'
Plugin 'AndrewRadev/linediff.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-markdown'
Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc'
Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax'
Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-after'
Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown'
Plugin 'scrooloose/vim-slumlord'
Plugin 'aklt/plantuml-syntax'
Plugin 'dolfly/plantuml'
Plugin 'iamcco/mathjax-support-for-mkdp'
Plugin 'iamcco/markdown-preview.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/UnconditionalPaste'
Plugin 'lervag/vimtex'
Plugin 'xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview'
Plugin 'gerw/vim-latex-suite'
Plugin 'brennier/quicktex'
Plugin 'mileszs/ack.vim'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
Plugin 'svermeulen/vim-easyclip'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-system-copy'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/SearchComplete'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git'
Plugin 'editorconfig/editorconfig-vim'
Plugin 'ivalkeen/nerdtree-execute'
Plugin 'KabbAmine/zeavim.vim'
Plugin 'baruchel/vim-notebook'
Plugin 'python-mode/python-mode'
Plugin 'SkyLeach/pudb.vim'
Plugin 'Mistobaan/pyclewn'
Plugin 'rhysd/devdocs.vim'
Plugin 'goerz/ipynb_notedown.vim'
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plugin 'jalcine/cmake.vim'
Plugin 'jansenm/vim-cmake'
Plugin 'aperezdc/vim-template'
Plugin 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete'
```

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down the originating plugin by successive removals of plugins from your setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of vim-latexsuite.

The `<++>` (with an optional comment between the two `+`) is a placeholder, which can be jumped to (without leaving insert mode) via `<C-j>`. So you can type in between `(` and `)` whatever you like, then move to after the closing parenthesis via `<C-j>`, without leaving insert mode.

This feature can be disabled by setting `g:Imap_UsePlaceHolders` to `0`. ([Documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-place-holders.html)) Personally, though, I can only recommend this little bit, in LaTeX as well as elsewhere -- it can be mighty useful, especially in combination with macros.